# vectorize loop for ckdtree search over two arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, kdtree

I have a csv file with latitude, longitude and elevation values at random places. I wanted to apply IDW interpolation to generate a regular grid. I used **scipy.spatial.cKDTree** for nearest neighbor search and find the elevation value at unknown points. 
The following code works fine when the output grid has dimensions (z < 1000 X1000). If the dimensions increase the code runs really slow. Please help me vectorize the **for loop** with out removing using cKDTree. Thank you.

```
## Inverse distance weighted function
def idw(p, dist, values):

    dist_pow = np.power(dist, 2)
    nominator = np.sum(values/dist_pow)
    denominator = np.sum(1/dist_pow)
    if denominator > 0:
        return nominator/denominator
    else:
        return none
## Reading the lat/lon and elevation values from file
lat = []
lon = []
ele = []

with open('VSKP_ground_dat.csv') as read:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(read)
    for row in csvreader:
        lat.append(float(row['LAT']))
        lon.append(float(row['LON']))
        ele.append(float(row['ALT']))
xycoord = np.c_[lon,lat]
ele_arr = np.array(ele)

## ------------- Creating KDTree
point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(xycoord, leafsize=25)
## ------------- Creating empty grid matrix with np.zeros
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax  = 81.903158, 83.352158, 17.25856, 18.40056
## --------- Defining resolution
xres, yres = 0.01, 0.01

x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, xres)
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax, yres)
z = np.zeros((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]), dtype=np.float16)


for i, val1 in enumerate(x):
    for j, val2 in enumerate(y):
        p = np.array([val1, val2])
        # points_idx = point_tree.query_ball_point(p, dist_2)
        distances, points_idx = point_tree.query(p, k=6, eps=0)
        ele_vals = ele_arr[points_idx]
        value = idw(p, distances, ele_vals)
        z[i,j] = value
```

Comment: what is the `idw` function?  You'd need to vectorize that to remove the `for` loops

Comment: Also please check through and make sure your variable names are consistent.  I assume `p` and `point` are supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes,  P and Point are same(my mistake) and IDW is inverse distance weighted interpolation function.

Comment: Do you have the code for that function?  Can you edit it into the question? (also edit your code to be correct, editing code in questions is frowned upon unless by the questioner)

Comment: I have added the function and corrected the typos in the loop. The loop with cKDTree is taking very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix up your `idw` function to work over the last index:

```
def idw(dist, values, p = 2):
    out = np.empty(dist.shape[:-1])
    mask = np.isclose(dist, 0).any(-1)
    out[mask] = values[np.isclose(dist, 0)]                   # should be only one per point
    dist_pow = np.power(dist[~mask], -p)                      # division is costly, do it once
    nominator = np.sum(values[~mask] * dist_pow, axis = -1)  # over mask to prevent divide by zero
    denominator = np.sum(dist_pow, index = -1)
    out[~mask] = nominator / denominator
    return out
```

Then do the rest based on `np.meshgrid` output

```
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, xres)                           # len i
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax, yres)                           # len j
xy = np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y), axis = -1)               # shape(i, j, 2)
distances, points_idx = point_tree.query(xy, k=6, eps=0)  # shape (i, j, 6)
ele_vals = ele_arr[points_idx]                            # shape (i, j, 6)
z = idw(distances, ele_vals)                              # shape (i, j)
```

Comment: I am getting the spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.query 
ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 2 but has shape (2, 115, 145). I have taken `lat = [17.749405, 17.788955, 17.805596, 17.817568,....]` and `lon = [81.903658, 81.940228, 81.97914, 82.008435, 82.009833, 82.03696, .....]`

Comment: Yeah, forgot the `axis` in `np.stack` to get the right shape.  Sorry!

Comment: This works great. Please change the `index` to `axis` in  IDW function and if possible please explain the IDW function in detail. Thanks for the help.